# Can't see </head> and <body> in page source. Is that normal?

Tags: html

Here's what the page source looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://...">
<!-- analytics -->
<script>
...
```

The ending `</head>` tag and the `<body>` tag should be between `<link rel=` and `<!-- analytics -->`.

The website seems to work just fine, but I was wondering if this is normal and if it might affect it negatively in some way.

Comment: That may depend on the tool you use to inspect the code. Try viewing the page source using "Show page source" (translated from German) in Chrome, it's the second last right click menu option. Web Developer tools may show you an interpreted view of the given file and not seeing `</head>` and `<body>` may be a sign that there is something wrong with your page structure.

Comment: Thanks for your input. In Chrome it looks just the same as in FF with Firebug: without a closing </head> and a starting </body>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal in the sense that the start and end tags for `head` and `body` may be omitted partially or completely. This has been the case since the earliest versions of HTML and has not changed in HTML5.

But sometimes where you place the `</head>` and `<body>` tags can make a difference. In your case, the element that follows the comment is a `script` element. Right now, that `script` element will get put in the page head, not the page body, because `script` elements may appear within either element and if the spot where the `script` element appears isn't already in the context of the `body` element (for example, because an element that may only appear in the document body was already encountered, which is not the case here), then the `script` element gets put in the head by default and not the body. See sections [8.2.5.4.4 The "in head" insertion mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inhead) and [8.2.5.4.7 The "in body" insertion mode](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#parsing-main-inbody) of HTML5.

Had you placed the `</head>` and `<body>` tags where you expect them to be like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://...">
</head>
<body>
<!-- analytics -->
<script>
...
```

Then the `script` element would appear as the first child of `body`, not the last child of `head`. This can affect a number of things, such as for example any `body > :first-child` selectors you might happen to have in your CSS where you're expecting something *other* than a `script` to be the first child. And since we're talking about a `script` element, if your script requires `document.body` in order to work, and it's not in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler for whatever reason, then *it won't work* if it's in the page head.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question above to make more sense (I thought images get embedded and not linked to, that's why I decided to use one). (And it looks like pressing Enter saves the comment - boy, I need to learn this.) In the code </head> and <body> tags _are_ placed exactly where you suggested they should be. However, when I check the source of the page in FF or Chrome, no such tags appear.

Comment: @Hamsun: That's super odd. You're using the old-school View Source and not the web inspector to look at the HTML, right?

Comment: Yes. "View page source" in both browsers, also Firebug in FF.

Comment: @Hamsun: Something is removing the tags from the markup before it gets served to the browser...

Comment: It's working now, in the sense that it's displaying both tags correctly. Unfortunately I made so many modifications that I'm not sure what did it. Possibly a misplaced `<?php } ?>`. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Hamsun Good you solved it, depending on the application you use to edit php files you may find the relevant change in "local history" or similar. Perhaps that would also be a good moment to start using local git repositories, that makes finding changes really easy ;-). Could you either accept BoltClock's answer or write your own and accept it? Thanks!

Comment: (In case you're unsure, the accept button is the checkmark icon underneath the voting arrows.)

Comment: @SaschaM78: sure! And thanks for the local git idea.

Answer (score 0):

Run it through the validator http://validator.w3.org  Some modern browsers "auto complete" these things but your markup should be semantic.  Older browsers might not like it.